# Why doesnt {highscorelist} have a value?

Tags: javascript, json, object, object-literal

```
const HIGHSCOREKEY = "highscore";

highscorelist = localStorage.getItem(HIGHSCOREKEY);
if(highscorelist){
    highscorelist = {
        one: {navn: "AAA", score: 0},
        two: {navn: "AAA", score: 0},
        three: {navn: "AAA", score: 0}
    };
    localStorage.setItem(HIGHSCOREKEY, JSON.stringify(highscorelist));
};
```

this is the code for it, when i try to do "highscorelist.one.score" it says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'one' of null"

Comment: can you also show your code for '"doing" highscorelist.one.score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem(HIGHSCOREKEY, JSON.stringify(highscorelist));` is equivalent to `localStorage.setItem(HIGHSCOREKEY, highscorelist);` as localStorage will store in the form of string.

So while retriving the data do

```
highscorelist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(HIGHSCOREKEY));
```

Comment: it still gives me the error? it kicks back on this code if(teller < highscorelist.one.score){
                    highscorelist.one.navn = naavn;
                }
teller is my counter and naavn = name

Comment: I think your localStorage is not setting the highscore key. Instead of `if(highscorelist)` I believe you need to do `if(!highscorelist)`.